# How to dynamically create the column in TYPE Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, pivot, user-defined-types

Some columns in TYPE object in Oracle needs to create Dynamically. Please let me know how can i achieve it.
            `l_row --> TYPE, sql_stmt--> is contain the Query`

Below is the part of the query in package.

```
        OPEN p_rc FOR sql_stmt;       
        LOOP            
        FETCH p_rc INTO l_row;      

        PIPE ROW(l_row);            
        EXIT WHEN p_rc%NOTFOUND;           
        END LOOP;
```

Below is the TYPE Structure

```
 TYPE test_service IS RECORD ( 
    column1                    VARCHAR2(3),   
    column2                   VARCHAR2(6),   
    column3                   VARCHAR2(1000),   
    column4                   VARCHAR2(1000),     
    Column5                   VARCHAR2(1000)

  );

   TYPE test_service_result IS TABLE OF test_service;
```

In this `column3`,`column4`,`column5` need to add dynamically.

Please find some portion of sqlstmt.

MERGEDATA, VALUESERVICE from REP_GTT_DATA ' || V_WHERE_CLAUSE ||' )PIVOT(MAX(MERGEDATA) FOR VALUESERVICE IN(' || pivot_clause || '))';

MergeData--> Is some values , 
ValueService--> now become columns for Mergedata values (i.e Column  3,4,5 etc..).

IF suppose Column5 (ValueService) value  not fetched from query then getting Exception.i.e **01007. 00000 -  "variable not in select list"** . 
Due to this reason i cant specify the column name declaration at the beginning,So from Column 3,4,5 etc should create dynamically based on the (ValueService)value. Please suggest how can i achieve it.

Comment: Do you mean you want to add `column3,column4,column5` to the RECORD definition dynamically? Or something else? Your question is not clear.

Comment: Now Added  more Details in Main Question. Hope this will helps in understanding the issue. Basically i am using the Pivot concept, So columns declaration should create dynamically in RECORD definition otherwise if some column value not fetched from Sql Stmnt then system throwing exception. Please find more detail now in Main question.

Comment: Type definitions,including records, are STATIC at compile time. So you cannot  do this without an exceptional amount of code. You need to drop the current definition and re-create it using dynamic sql, Also any sql statements using it would also have to be dynamic - both in the procedure and in all routines calling it.  It appears you are attempting to use your record definition as a general collect all for multiple queries but it doesn't work that way.  As far as your sample of a column not being selected you could just select NULL for the missing column, but this gets nasty quickly.